# How can I change file permissions with winjs

Tags: angularjs, windows-8.1, winjs

I am currently working on a windows 8 winJS/AngularJS application and we want to make some files that are being stored in the LocalState folder to have their permissions changed to be read-only. The files are images taken with the camera and we want to discourage changing the images after saving them.

Any ideas would be great. I am using  Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync() to get the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the StorageFile.properties.retrievePropertiesAsync and savePropertiesAsync methods to do this. Here's a piece of code that makes a file read-only, where I define the read-only attribute as it's found in the Win32 API:

```
var key = "System.FileAttributes";
var FILE_ATTRIBUTES_READONLY = 1;  //From the Win32 API

var file;  

//Assign some StorageFile to the file variable  
file.properties.retrievePropertiesAsync([key]).then(function (props) {
     if (props) {
         props[key] |= FILE_ATTRIBUTES_READONLY;
     } else {
         props = new Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet();
         props.insert(key, FILE_ATTRIBUTES_READONLY);
     }  

    return file.properties.savePropertiesAsync(props);
}).done(function () {
    //Any other action
});
```

You can use a WinRT component as Rob says, but there's no need.

I have a full discussion of file properties in my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), Chapter 11, starting on page 592. The code above is directly from page 601.